# Upgrade from identity server 3 to identity server4

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4, identityserver3

We are planning to upgrade our current implementation of identity server 3 to identity server 4. Is this easily achievable? 
IdentityServer is compiled against both netstandard 1.4 and .NET 4.5.2 or above.

Our current project is in MVC and using .net framework 4.5.2. I have downloaded latest code of IS4 and added to my project. And there are separate library created for views/controllers.

For reference I am attaching screen shot of current code structure.
Do we have any step by step procedure available that need to be followed in this up-gradation process?

If I missed to share any information about project .. sorry in advance.
Please help!

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

They are completely different and there's no direct migration path unfortunately.